# Is it possible to run Calabash-IOS, iOS automated tests on Ubuntu?

Tags: ios, linux, ubuntu, automated-tests, calabash-ios

I know that it's impossible to code the test on `Ubuntu` since I need `Apple's XCODE`, but I would like to know if, once coded, it is possible to run the automated tests on `Ubuntu`.

Thanks.

Comment: from what i have read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/calabash-ios/bhSFAFipu9o/60maIKocCWUJ it seems fesable

Comment: I found the same article,but nothing concrete.